# Email Template Outlook alignment issue

Tags: html, css, dom, media-queries

Email Template Outlook window dekstop alignment issue

- [Actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qUaQ.png)
- [Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL51D.png)
- [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a5Ci.png)

```html
<tr style="background-color: #eaeaea;">
  <td align="left" bgcolor="#eaeaea" class="one-hundred-percent paragraph-top-padding" style="Margin: 0 auto; padding:0;vertical-align: middle; display: block; width: 100%; text-align: left;" width="100%">
    <p class="body-text-font" style="-moz-hyphens:none;-webkit-hyphens:none; Margin: 0;  margin:0; margin-left: 20px; padding: 0; padding-top: 4px; color:#414042;font-family:'Locator', 'Open Sans', Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px; hyphens:none;line-height:19px;overflow-wrap:normal; text-align:left; word-break:normal;width:100%; font-weight: normal;"
      width="100%">
      [DataClasses] - Compromised data: Dates of birth, Email addresses, Genders, Names, Passwords, Phone numbers, Physical addresses
    </p>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have learned with Outlook is rather than do `padding:0;` or `margin:0;` you have to list the values out separately `padding-top:VALUE; padding-right:VALUE; padding-bottom:VALUE; padding-left:VALUE;`

You also have `padding` and `padding-top` and `margin` and `margin-left` which could be causing issues since you are setting the parameter multiple ways and Outlook is very touchy.